# Why would anyone declare a variable before defining it? Please provide example

Tags: java, c#, variables, initialization, variable-declaration

I'm just now learning c# (my second language, first being python) and i thought it was strange that you could declare variables before ever defining what they are. Here's what I mean:

```
string str;
//then later, you can do
str = "Bob"
```

what's the point? is there any logical use case that makes declaring a variable before use the only/best option? Is it faster? Not a big deal, I'm just hung up on this and cant find a cohesive answer anywhere on the internet. Thanks!

(big shoutout to random people online who take their precious time to answer questions of people like me. Really shows character that there are people out there who take time to do stuff like this, so thank you!)

Comment: also meant to set str as int not string lol

Comment: Some types in some languages are assigned a default value.

Comment: No point in your example. Two cases where there is a point: (1) I declare a variable, then put an `if`-`else` statement and give the variable a value in each of the cases. (2) I use a Boolean variable to control a `do`-`while` loop. I need to declare the variable before the loop even though I don’t give it a value until inside the loop.

Comment: Do you mean local variables, or is your question about members (instance variables in Java) too?

Comment: I think you mean "assigning" rather than "defining". Not sure whether some other language(s) use that terminology but I've certainly never heard "define" used in that context in C#. In fact, "define" and "declare" are pretty much synonyms in C#.

Comment: There can certainly be valid reason to declare a variable and not assign a value to it until later, but I definitely see people do it when there's no need or point. That especially applies to beginners, who haven't learned best practice yet. If you're ever in a scenario where it's required you will know it, because it won't work otherwise.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I seem to remember that C++ makes a very clear distinction between declaring and defining, be it variables or functions. Probably other languages too (C?)

Comment: Outside technical reasons there are teams that give themselves the style requirement to have all local variables declared at the top of a block. Whether that's good or bad may be highly opinionated but there is the "style" aspect that I wanted to throw in.

Comment: @Fildor Yes, that "style" exists. I always thought of it as coming from Pascal and other languages that in their syntax keep declaration and assignment apart. I have not understood why anyone would actively prefer it except out of habit.

Comment: I guess habit takes a big chunk of it, yes. People in C# nowadays may have started with it, so don't carry so much "baggage". But when it was still fairly new, it was pretty common that people cane from other backgrounds. Like C, Java, Pascal-based langs ... all with very distinct expectations of what "readable code" would look like. That's not a thing specific to C#, though. That's always quite a task when getting "fluent" in a new language. ('New' to the individual)

Answer (score 2):

Useful when you are using loops

```csharp
string str;

for(int x=0;x<10; x++)
{
    str = x.ToString();
}

Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Now if you did declare the variable inside the loop you won't be able to access it outside.

Answer (score 2):

## Because i don't know its value yet.

Firstly you should know the difference between those terms **Declaration**, **Definition** and **Initialization**.

Sometimes you need to only *declare* a variable without giving it a value (not *initialized*), that's because you don't know its value until now or even it's an instance variable (class member) in which the client of the class will pass its value at creation.

**Instance variable example:**

```
class Player{
 
  int speed; // why didn't i initialize those variables 
  String name;

 Player(String name, int speed){

  this.name = name; //it's time to initialize

  this.speed = speed;
 }
}
```

Some variables must wait until their values get known, like the example above.

**Local variable example**

```
bool isEven; // whether a number is even or not
for(int i = 1 ; i <= 100 ; i++){

 if((i%2) == 0){ // now, i know it's value 
   isEven = true;
  }
 else{ 
   isEven = false;
  }
 System.out.println(isEven);
}
```

let me know if you need some explanation of the three terms (Declaration,...) above.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: local variabe != instance variable

Comment: @Chalieface ok, i will provide an example for local var

Comment: I believe that most prefer `bool isEven = (i % 2) == 0;`. I still agree with the principle, in many similar cases I would put the declaration outside the control structure and assign a value inside of it.

Comment: @Anonymous both works, but i separated variable declaration from initialization to be related to the question.

Comment: _"Because i don't know its value yet."_ - calling functions of the `bool TrySomething( string arg , out int count )` pattern variety comes to mind ...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is (generally) - if you want to assign a value to the variable in some inner scope and use it in the outer scope. Scope can be created by using statement, loops, try-catch.

There is already an example with loop, so I'm going with try-catch. Consider the following use-case: you are querying some storage to get user by their id and do some processing. Storage can be inaccessible due to several reasons (network failure, storage is down, etc). So it is a common practice to wrap such calls with try-catch statement to catch and log error.

```
// calls any storage under the hood: sql db, redis, aws, etc
private readonly IUserRepository _repo;

...

public async Task GetAndProcessUserAsync(int id)
{
    User? user;
    try
    {
        user = _repo.GetUserByIdAsync(id);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Error while accessing storage");
    }
    //process user somehow
    ProcessUser(user); 
}
```

Comment: While it is legitimate to separate declaration and assignment in such cases, in your particular example I would personally prefer to return the user from within the `try` part. Or if you don’t want that, then explicitly initialize the variable in the declaration -- for example to hull.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to add some user-related processing but forgot about it. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Think of it as defining or telling the compiler you are creating a box, which is ready to be fed information or defined later on. Or you could take another example being partitioning a drive with a certain file system being, let's say, either NTFS or ext4 - just because you are preparing your storage device to store data or information you don't necessarily have to fill it up right away.

For some code or for some solutions it might make sense to have everything declared before filling up the variables, or boxes so to speak, abstracting for the person reading the code what is about to happen. The person studying and analyzing the code would be able to immediately pick up on what is going to happen and deduct the flow and structure of the rest of the code.

In other cases you might declare and initialize/assign on-the-go.

You could also compare it to reading a book on a subject without a table of contents or reading a scientific journal without an abstract.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. I think that the example that the OP requested would have made it clearer what you mean.

Comment: @Anonymous Huh?

Comment: The question was about the point in separating variable declaration from initialization (assigning a value to the variable) in contrast to doing both at once, as in `string str = "Bob";`. I have not understood how your answer answers that question.

Comment: @Anonymous He is using his own declaration as an example and then asks 'why' is one able to declare without assigning or giving a value. I do not need to adhere to an example meant to shine a light on the meaning and purpose of a question.  Declaring fields per se and then assigning them or giving them a value in the constructor for example could be a realistic use case scenario of declaring before assigning. Why do you even comment? The answer isn't even meant for you.

Comment: When I read the question again, I can understand how you could misread it that way. No, that is not what they asked. And why I comment? I always appreciate criticism on my posts and find them helpful, so thought it might be helpful for you too. If you don’t like it, I can just delete all my comments again, no problem.

Comment: @Anonymous No - you are misreading the question thinking you're understanding it right This has nothing to with criticism, which I naturally also appreciate where it's duly prompted, but you have completely misunderstood his question if you think his example of a declaration had anything to do with his actual question. You comments can be left up, I have no issue with that - however before commenting on others answers make sure that you understand what is actually be inquired about.

Comment: Thanks for that comment. It’s a simple disagreement of interpretation, and only the OP can tell who’s right.